# Prove that: $\vdash \forall x \exists !y(y=x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Prove that: $$\vdash \forall x \exists !y(y=x)$$ in first order logic.

The first thing to do would be to write this as $$\forall x (\exists y(y=x) \land \forall y\forall z (y=x \land z=x \to y=z))$$

However, I cannot proceed from here. The equality axioms of first order theories don't seem to give me anything.

Comment: I'm not familiar with first order logic, but can't you pick $y=x$ to show existence and use transitivity and symmetry to show that $y$ is unique?

Comment: That is intuitively obvious but I am not able to prove it formally in first order logic @Farnight.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a formal matter, thus I will describe how you do this formally using proof rules.

In order to prove
$$\forall x (\exists y(y=x) \land \forall y\forall z (y=x \land z=x \to y=z))$$
We show that 
$$\exists y(y=a) \land \forall y\forall z (y=a \land z=a \to y=z))$$
hold for a general constant $a$, and then if we want to be formal use $\forall$-introduction.

To prove $\exists y(y=a)$ we may just notice that $a=a$ hold by $=-$introduction and then use $\exists$-intrudction to prove $\exists y(y=a)$. If we want to use the axioms for equality instead of the $=-$introduction rule, we may use $\forall x(x=x)$ and use $\forall-$elimination to conclude that $a=a$ hold and then continue as above.

In order to prove $\forall y\forall z (y=a \land z=a \to y=z))$ We assume that $b,c$ are general constants such that $b=a\land c=a$ hold. Now we may use $=$-elimination (or equality axioms) to conclude that $b=c$ hold. If we want to use the axioms for equality instead we may use the axiom $\forall x\forall y (y=x \wedge P(x)\rightarrow P(y))$, which should hold for any predicate $P$ Thus it also hold if P is the predicate $c=x$. In this case we get the formula
$$\forall x\forall y (y=x \wedge x=c\rightarrow y=c)$$
If we do $\forall-$eliminationputting in $a$ and $c$ we get $a=b\wedge b=c\rightarrow a = c$. which we may use to prove what we wanted.

To finnish the proof we use $\forall-introduction to conclude the formla we want to prove.

Comment: Can you exactly state which axiom you have used where? The first axiom states that $\forall x(x=x)$. How have you used it here?

Comment: @Apurv I've edited the answer to include the use of axioms for equality.

Answer (score -1):

That was tricky! This isn't standard FOL, but you should be able to translate it if you are familiar with all the "subtleties" of standard FOL (I am not). I introduce the unary predicate $U$ to make the domain of discussion explicit. (This is not the usual practice in standard FOL.) Using this convention, we want to prove:

$$\forall x:[U(x) \implies \exists y:[U(y) \land [x=y \land \forall z:[U(z)\implies [x=z \implies y=z]]]]]$$

Proof:

1. $U(a)$  (Premise)
2. $a=a$  (Reflexivity)
3. $U(c)$  (Premise)
4. $a=c$  (Premise)
5. $a=c \implies a=c$  (Conclusion, 4)
6. $\forall z:[U(z) \implies [a=z \implies a=z]]$ (Conclusion, 3)
7. $a=a \land \forall z:[U(z) \implies [a=z \implies a=z]]$  (Join, 2,6)
8. $U(a) \land [a=a \land \forall z:[U(z) \implies [a=z \implies a=z]]]$  (Join, 1, 7)
9. $\exists y:[U(y) \land [a=y \land \forall z:[U(z) \implies [a=z \implies y=z]]]$ (E Gen, 8)
10. $\forall x:[U(x) \implies \exists y:[U(y) \land [x=y \land \forall z:[U(z)\implies [x=z \implies y=z]]]]]$ (Conclusion, 1)